# Is there a pixel limit for HTML element placement with CSS?

Tags: css, user-interface

I recently had to place an HTML element far off the page with CSS. I did `position: fixed; left: a lot of pixels`. I didn't notice any performance decrease in Chrome, but could it potentially cause issues?

Comment: you don't need *a lot of pixels*, you only need `left:100%`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm just asking theoretically. Of course it's not necessary or practical. But I'll use the 100% instead, thanks.